# Fourth root in denominator for derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives, roots

The problem I'm working with right now looks like this

$$\dfrac{(6x^3 + x)(4x-2x^2)}{3 \cdot x^\frac14}$$

How do I deal with the fourth root in the denominator to find the derivative? This problem's really driving me crazy.

Comment: I would suggest expand everything...

Comment: Also, the three fractions still apply

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

After expanding/rewriting you get $$-\dfrac{\left(4x-2x^2\right)\left(6x^3+x\right)}{12x^\frac{5}{4}}+\dfrac{\left(4-4x\right)\left(6x^3+x\right)}{3\sqrt[4]{x}}+\dfrac{\left(4x-2x^2\right)\left(18x^2+1\right)}{3\sqrt[4]{x}}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: did you get this with the quotient rule [g(x)*f '(x) - f(x)* g ' (x)] / [g(x)^2] ?

Comment: I used the product rule.

Comment: my biggest issue is that i'm working in a non-calculator course so I don't know how to work with this problem and getting the 12x^(5/4) naturally without using a calculator

Comment: You don't need to solve that. If you multiply $12x^{\frac54}$ and $3\sqrt[4]{x}$ you get $36x^\frac 32$.